# Rails: Auto-increment column while preserving cardinality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on an implementing a feature with a scenario similar to this: 
`Company` has many `Items`and each `Item` has a column called `company_item_number`.

I'm looking for a way to increment the `company_item_number` as a new item is added into a particular `Company`, preserving cardinality even after an item is deleted.

Note that this is different than `item_id` which will auto increment whenever *any* item is added by *any* `Company`.

For example:

**Company A**

- company_item_number: 1
- company_item_number: 2
- company_item_number: 3 (removed/deleted)
- company_item_number: 4

**Company B**

- company_item_number: 1 (removed/deleted)
- company_item_number: 2

As you can see, I also need to make sure that if a previous item was deleted, the next item_number should be +1 greater than the previously deleted item, preserving cardinality.

Any thoughts on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried having a column on Company called "last_item_number_count" which gets auto-incremented for ever new item; however, this requires that I query this number before I set the company_item_number on item creation. Also, this approach just feels weird (I don't like keeping track of the last incremented value separately).

Answer (score 0):

This is complicated by your requirement that cardinality be preserved even when records are deleted. I would personally suggest never *actually* deleting Item records; instead, add a `removed_at` timestamp column which you can check to decide if an item was removed or not. Then, your approach gets much simpler (for this task, and likely for many other tasks). With that, you could use a `before_create` hook, which runs right before your new record is saved into the database, to populate the field on each record, like so:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create do |item|
     current_highest = Item.where(company_id: item.company_id).pluck("MAX(company_item_number)").first
     item.company_item_number = (current_highest || 0) + 1
   end
end
```

If you don't want to go that route, your `companies.last_item_number_count` idea seems like a good option. Alternatively, a new `company_item_numbers` table from which you never remove records would serve a similar purpose. Ultimately, without some record of the deleted items having been present, there's no way to ensure you aren't re-using a number you already used.